# Automatic creation of ListViewSubItems

Tags: c#, listview, .net-2.0, controls

Hai,

I tried to create a **ListViewControl** (tile mode) and added a *ListViewItem*. I created it like this,

```
ListViewItem aFooItem = new ListViewItem("foo");
listView1.Items.Add(aFooItem);  //Adding the ListViewItem to the ListViewControl
```

Now I ran the application and tried to debug the first line. I found that the aFooItem's subitems count is 1 and is similar to aFooItem itself. Could somebody help me why the aFooItem's SubItems.Count is 1, even thou' I didn't add an item to it explicitly ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default value of a `ListViewItem` *is* the value of the sub-item at index 0. When you create a `ListViewItem` it automatically creates the default sub-item for you.

Answer (score 1):

A ListViewItem's "SubItems" is the list of columns it contains. By initializing your ListViewItem with a default string ("foo") you've added one subitem (with Text == "foo").